# Linux shell - How to find for all running process if the file has been removed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to identify if there is a process that is running for which the file (of the related process) does not exist anymore.

So far I have:

```
# [ ! -f /my/file ]; than echo "NOT exist!"; fi
```

to understand if a file exists or not

now I need from the list of processes, extract the files that generated the process, remove the arguments, and verify if the file exist or not...
but I'm struggling to make it work.
Plus I have to be careful for process like:
/bin/sh /my/script.sh
/usr/bin/python /my/python_file

(for this second case I can partially identify if script.sh or python_file have been deleted by using "lsof | grep deleted")

do you know if there is a smart way to do it please?
Thank you 
dk

Comment: I believe you could `lsof` to get a list of all open files and their associated processes. Not sure if it will list files that don't exist though.. since they don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lsof lists deleted files as /path/to/file (deleted)

So as root, this should give you a list of all deleted files:
lsof | grep '(deleted)'

After that, you could shorten the list by matching the filename with the executable name (if it matches, it's potentially a deleted executable running).

I would also match all the executables that are known to run scripts (ruby, perl, etc.). Even better, I would rather filter out the executables who don't and manually verify each remaining false positive.

## Proof

Compiling this small program:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for ( ; ; ) {
    }

    return 0;
}

$ gcc useless.c -o useless
```

running it

```
$ ./useless
```

then deleting it (in another terminal):

```
$ rm useless
```

Running lsof as root shows:

```
useless     738             dioo  txt       REG                8,4       7955      40685 /home/dioo/useless (deleted)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure it would have worked with all the cases. So the easyest solution seems to be also the most effective one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on linux, I'd trawl through /proc

```
shopt -s extglob
for dir in /proc/+([0-9]); do
    # examine $dir/comm and decide if this is a script interpreter
    # like bash/python/perl ...

    # if yes, get the script name with
    my_script=$( cut -d '' -f 2 $dir/cmdline )

    # decide if the program or script file is missing
done
```